# Retrieving values of custom fields in Quick Edit mode

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, quick-edit

I've been trying to add a field to Quick Edit. Somehow it works: it is displayed and if you enter a value in the input field, the value is saved into a custom field. However, can't seem to find a way to retrieve the value of the custom field. Here's what I got so far:

```
add_action('quick_edit_custom_box', 'ilc_quickedit_show', 10, 2);
function ilc_quickedit_show( $col, $type ) {
    if( $type != 'event' ) return; ?>

    <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-left">
        <div class="inline-edit-col">
            <div class="inline-edit-group">
                <label for="eventdate" style="font: italic 12px Georgia, serif;">Event Date</label>
                <span class="input-text-wrap">
                    <input type="text" name="eventdate" id="eventdate" size="10" value="">
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <?php
}
```

entered values are saved using:

```
add_action('save_post','ilc_quickedit_save',10,3);
function ilc_quickedit_save($post_id, $post) {
    if( $post->post_type != 'event' ) return;
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'Event Date', $_POST['eventdate']);
}
```

As you surely noticed, this is for a custom post type 'event'. However, I can't retrieve the values and populate the fields. AFAIK, this involves inline-edit-post.js but I can't find any way to use inlineEditPost to retrieve the custom field value. Even the post id is available in the JavaScript scope

```
add_action('admin_head-edit.php', 'ilc_quickedit_get');
function ilc_quickedit_get() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('a.editinline').live('click', function() {
            var id = inlineEditPost.getId(this);
            alert("Post id: " + id);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Downloaded the Custom Field Template plugin to dissect the code and found that they are redefining portions of the inlineEditPost function, so I thought about doing the same thing. However, they appear to be doing it through an options array where a duplicate is stored.
If you have solved this, could you share what you're using to retrieve the values for each custom field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it, here's the code:

```
function ilc_quickedit_save($post_id, $post) {
    if( $post->post_type != 'evento' ) return;
    if (isset($_POST['is_quickedit']))
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'eventdate', $_POST['eventdate']);
}

function ilc_quickedit_get() { 
    $html = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $html .= 'jQuery(document).ready(function() {';
        $html .= 'jQuery("a.editinline").live("click", function() {';

        $html .= 'var id = inlineEditPost.getId(this);';
        $html .= 'jQuery.post("' . THEME_URI . '/library/admin/admin.php",{ post_id: id, modo: "ajaxget" },';
        $html .= 'function(data){ jQuery("#eventdate").val(data); }';

    $html .= ');});});';
    $html .= '</script>';
    echo $html;
}
```

and the code at the beginning of the admin.php file (which is the same file where all this code is located):

```
if($_POST['modo'] == 'ajaxget'){
    require_once('../../../../../wp-blog-header.php');
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'eventdate', true);
    return;
}
```

So far so good, maybe there are other ways to do it. Still need to deal with saving while in bulk editing mode. Could use a hand there too :) Hope this is useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

This is **untested** code. See if it works for you. Basically, as you'll read below, I globalize `$post`, check for your CPT, and then retrieve the custom field `event` from the post's meta (returning a single value -- as set by the "true" in the last parameter).

The only thing you have to do is reference `$event` in your jQuery like so: `{$event}` to output the value into the javascript. It'll appear "static" but in reality it's dynamic.

```
add_action('admin_head-edit.php', 'ilc_quickedit_get');

function ilc_quickedit_get()
{
    global $post;

    if ( $post->post_type != "event" )
        return;

    $event = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'event', true ); // gets a *single* option from the postmeta table

$html = <<<HTML
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('a.editinline').live('click', function() {
            // do something with {$event}
        });
    });
</script>
HTML;

    echo $html;
}
```

**P.S.** I assigned your HTML code to a PHP variable to make it easier to read and allow you to quickly reference `$event` in the jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Zack. The admin_head-edit.php is a hook called at the header so if you reference global $post you end up with the id of the first post. It would have been easy and intuitive to do it in a similar way: having a hook that executes for each post row.
What I'm trying now is an AJAX get request to a php where the custom field values are returned. We'll see what happens.
Thanks again!

Comment: Hmmm... I'll have to think about this one a bit.